# Java 8 Collectors API

Tags: java, mapping, java-8, collectors

This question involves mapping and grouping of elements using java 8 collectors.
I've got a list of Patient. Each Patient has a list of departments he had visited.
Say I want to count for each departments how many time it had been visited using the new collectors API in java 8, how would I group by the departments list?

Thanks!

**NOTE:** I know that I can put a counter in each of the departments, this question is solely for the purpose of learning the new java 8 features.

Code:

```
public class Patient {
    private String id;
    private List<Department> history;
    /* some more getters/setters come here */
}
```

In my main method I have a list of Patient. I want to know for each Department, how many time it had been visited, without editing the Department class (or extending or decorating it).

I think I have to take a stream of patients and map them to a map of dept->count (how many times each patient visited which dept.). Having a stream of these maps - I have no idea what to do to group these maps and count them.

Comment: This is probably best explained by code. Please define your Patient and Department code so everybody can hook in on that.

Comment: @owlstead: I added the fields of class Patient. This should be simple I just can't find how to do it. Notice that I didn't add the code for Department because it has no significance, it could be easily a String

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, I'll assume that if a Patient has visited a Department more than once, that Department will appear in the Patient's history list more than once.

If that's the case, then we can simply take our Stream of Patients and `flatMap` it to a Stream of Departments, where the occurrence of a Department indicates one visit from a Patient.

Then we can pass this to the `groupingBy` collector. We want to classify by Department itself, so the classifier function is the identity function.

For the value, we want to put a 1 as the value if an entry for the Department isn't present yet, but we want to add 1 to the existing value if an entry is present. There's a collector called `counting()` that does this for us already, so we just pass it as a downstream collector to `groupingBy()`.

The resulting code is as follows:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

List<Patient> patients = ... ;

Map<Department, Long> frequency =
    patients.stream()
        .flatMap(p -> p.getHistory().stream())
        .collect(groupingBy(d -> d, counting()));
```

Note that if a Department hasn't been visited, it will simply be absent from the map. If you have a list of departments, you can fill in the zero values like this:

```
departments.forEach(d -> frequency.putIfAbsent(d, 0L));
```

or if you want to fill in the zero on the `get` side,

```
long numVisits = frequency.getOrDefault(dept, 0L);
```

Comment: Looks simple enough, and seems to work. You should note that you've statically imported Collectors though. Could you please explain the logic of the solution?

Comment: @nocgod I think I was typing in the explanation at the same time you were asking for it. :-)

Comment: I guess you were :) I'll have to make a little switch to get into this whole functional lambda style - didn't touch it since my PPL course and scheme language. Thanks again!